# Where to find beautiful PHP code to read?

Tags: php

As a way to find inspiration and improve my PHP skills, I am looking for some beautiful PHP source code to read, preferably an open source "standard" web site rather than a more tool-like project such as phpMyAdmin.

So, where can I find some beautiful PHP code?

Comment: phpMyAdmin has some of the ugliest code ever...

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CodeIgniter code is beautiful. There are many projects written in CodeIgniter which are publically available and you can check out the source code.

Have a look at the [Getting started](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/getting_started.html) page of CodeIgniter's tutorial and read through. I can gaurantee you'll be inspired and want to fire up your IDE and get coding straight away :).

You can also download and have a look at the source code of [Bamboo invoice](http://bambooinvoice.org/). When I need inspiration I also search for 'php code' on youtube :)

Comment: The one ugly thing about CodeIgniter is its PHP4-compatibility. It would probably look nicer without it.

Comment: I don't want to get into a flame war, but I'd vote against CodeIgniter now as it's not very modern. It may have some beautiful code, but it's missing out on lots of modern features. I'd go for Symfony2 or zf2 instead.

Answer (score 8):

Not all opensource projects are great examples as of how things are done.

Take a look at [PEAR](http://pear.php.net), [ezComponents](http://ezcomponents.org/) and the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com). All three are pretty popular in the PHP world, they solve a ton of different problems [each sometimes with a different approach] and they all follow great coding standards.

Also, there is often a trade-off between beautiful/elegant code and code that is very optimized. For example, if you want to see code that is powered to run a large website which needs to handle a lot of traffic, check out [Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki). It's build on very efficient code, but it's not very pretty.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the dissonance between elegance and performance

Comment: Also note that beauty is very subjective. For instance, I would *never* recommend ezComponents or Zend Framework as examples of beautiful code as I find both of them difficult to read, far too verbose - and needlessly so. Like trying to use PHP as Java. But both are extremes and given the general low quality of PHP code they strike as something that at least follows *some* coding principles.

Comment: I agree that this is very subjective. Beautiful code can mean a lot of different things – e.g. it's nice to read and elegant. In that sense I prefer verbosity over magic. Sometimes beautiful code is also the opposite.

Answer (score 7):

Try looking at the source of the best PHP frameworks - Zend's, Symfony and CakePHP. They are very well documented and generally well designed.

Comment: I'd argue Cake.  You can **build** beautifully coded applications with Cake, but last times I plumbed the depths (about a year ago) there was a ton of ugly needed for PHP 4 compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

Kohana and Zend Framework i'd say. Zend's coding standards is also a good read.

Answer (score 5):

PHPUnit consists of great PHP5.3 code http://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/tree/

Also the Lithium Framework uses great PHP 5.3 code http://rad-dev.org/lithium/source

Answer (score 4):

http://fatfree.sourceforge.net/
so minimal it's insane

http://fuelphp.com/
very easy to use

https://github.com/auraphp
Aura has some really interesting standalone packages on offer

Comment: If you like F3 check http://phunction.sf.net/. ;)

Comment: cheers @Alix Axel - I'll take a look!

Answer (score 1):

[ezComponents](http://ezcomponents.org/): Well documented, and has very handy tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Krugle.org is a great place to browse for code. Not just PHP, of course.

Answer (score 0):

PHP.net is an open source website, but isn't exactly beautiful - some of it feels archaic but it works and is very secure.

[Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) is worth looking at, and there are some projects in the [PHP.net CVS](http://cvs.php.net/) that are a bit more modern than the website.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at "Expert PHP 5 tools" book. **There is e-book available in web also**.